# Azure Service Bus topic custom role permissions

Tags: azureservicebus

I'm trying to create a managed identity with a custom role that will provide access to create new subscriptions in my service bus topic.

My clients need to have the ability only to create subscriptions, but not to remove or edit.

As I see I can give them access only to create AND update subscriptions, but I want them to have access only for creating subscriptions. Is it possible to achieve that by creating a custom role?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Per the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/preview/subscriptions) in **ServiceBus Topic Subscription** ***permission*** we have only four Operations which follows:

- Create Or Update
- Delete
- Get
- List by Topics

There is no other way to do only **Create** Operation in ***ServiceBus Topic Subscription*** in **Custom Role**.

Please refer [Subscriptions - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/preview/subscriptions/create-or-update) for more information